# On the basis of 1st column print both the file

Tags: awk, sed

I have two files with multiple rows.
1st file have 2 colums and second file have more than 2000 colums.
Example data sets are:

Example File_1

```
car Maruti
car TATA
car Hyundai
car Jaguar
Jeep Mahindra
```

Example File_2

```
car  A B C D E F G
Jeep X Y Z W Q W K
```

I have tried this

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$0} ++n[$1]==2{print a[$1]}' File_2 File_1
```

Tho output of this command print the data only single time and not in perfect order. I got the following result:

```
car  A B C D E F G car Maruti
Jeep X Y Z W Q W K Jeep Mahindra
```

Expected Output on the basis of 1st file is:

```
car  Maruti    car  A B C D E F G
car  TATA      car  A B C D E F G
car  Hyundai   car  A B C D E F G
car  Jauar     car  A B C D E F G
Jeep Mahindra  Jeep X Y Z W Q W K
```

Comment: Does the output have to be exactly in that order or would a sorted output be acceptable too?

Comment: Both the outputs are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}'  file2 file1 | column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
car   Maruti    car   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
car   TATA      car   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
car   Hyundai   car   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
car   Jaguar    car   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
Jeep  Mahindra  Jeep  X  Y  Z  W  Q  W  K
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use the `join` command here which is specifically made for tasks like yours. However, `join` requires sorted files, so we sort first.

With `bash` the sorting can be done in-place

```
join <(sort 1stFile) <(sort 2ndFile)
```

With a plain posix shell (`sh`) you have to use temporary files

```
 sort 1stFile > 1stFileSorted
 sort 2ndFile > 2ndFileSorted
 join 1stFileSorted 2ndFileSorted
 rm 1stFileSorted 2ndFileSorted
```

To align the columns in the output you can use `join … | column -t`.